# How can I edit or view a Mac OS file with no extension?

Tags: macos

I would like to view or perhaps edit a file with no extension. It is a Mac OS X Universal Binary executable file which I downloaded from my iPhone.

I have both Mac OS X and Windows. Is there any way I could possibly open that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OS X, either use the normal *TextEdit.app*, or download a Hex editor like [**Hex Fiend**](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) and open the file.

[image]

However, there's not really a point in *editing* an executable file unless you specifically know what you're doing and what you're looking for (and I really doubt that). You'll probably just break its functionality.

If you have a file with no extension and you don't know what it is, use the `file` command from a Terminal to check.

```
$ file /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```